# NullPointerException at oracle.jbo.server.RemotableCompDef.ensureCodeSource

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created a select one choice list. The query brings back correct results in the sql developer from the database, but when I run the page on weblogic server it returns a nullpointer exception upon opening the page. I have tried restarting, cleaning up the application, creating a new List Of Values... I cannot find the cause of the problem. The tables inside the database seem ok. The same error appears in the Application Module if I run it separately (only the view objects,without the server or the page).
The query is like this:

SELECT t.ID, t.CD, nvl(l.DSCR, t.DSCR) DSCR
FROM MY_TABLE t,
(SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_LT lt WHERE UPPER(lt.CD_LANG) = UPPER(:p_locale)) l
WHERE t.ID = l.HD_ID(+)
AND t.ORG_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE(GET_ACCESSIBLE_ORG_IDS(:p_orgId)))

I work on oracle DB

Any idea might help work this out.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you tell us your exact JDev version, please? By 'opening the page in WebLogic...' you mean you run the app in the local WLS that is integrated in JDev?

Comment: Yes I run it locally in the integrated weblogicserver. The version of JDev is 12.2.1.3

Comment: Show us how you build the LOV, please. Which DB (oracle, mssql,...) do you use?